# What is the difference between TabLayout.TabView and TabLayout.Tab

Tags: android, android-tablayout, android-tabs

I'm trying to understand the difference between both classes that are both inner class of TabLayout class.
In the following link : [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44244469/how-to-change-selected-tab-title-textsize-in-android)

I see that method **onTabSelectedd(TabLayout.Tab tab)** in the example, gets a reference to **Tab** object, and for a reason that i can't understand, it is written there:

```
 ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) tabLayout.getChildAt(0);
 ViewGroup vgTab = (ViewGroup) vg.getChildAt(tab.getPosition());
```

is **Tab** object enough? the way i see the things the second line should return the same object as **Tab** that it a parameter of the above method.
When i'm printing toString() for both objects i see that the parameter *tab* is instance of **TabView** and *vgTab* is instance of **Tab**
Can someone explain me my misunderstanding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TabLayout.Tab` is not a subclass of `View`. It is a "conceptual" tab, an object that holds all the information necessary to render a single tab in a `TabLayout` (text, icon, etc).

`TabLayout.TabView` is a subclass of `View`. It knows how to take a `Tab` and render its text, its icon, etc.

In your linked question and answer, the reason for code like this:

> ```
> ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) tabLayout.getChildAt(0);
> ViewGroup vgTab = (ViewGroup) vg.getChildAt(tab.getPosition());
> ```

is that the `onTabSelected()` method only receives an argument of type `Tab`, but needs to do view-related things (change text size), so it must take that `Tab` and "find" the corresponding `TabView` that goes with it.

The code is assuming that the first child of the `tabLayout` is going to be a container of tab views, and then within that container it looks for the view at the same position as the parameter tab. Then it scans all children of *that* view, and changes the text size of any `TextView` it finds.

Comment: @Wow thanks a lot for the detailed answer. *But* i found 2 issues in your answer that i want to ask about them please: 1. Is the **tab** position attribute compatible with the position of the **TabView** inside the **TabLayout**?  2. Can't i think of **tab** as kind of *holder* that hold *TabView* data? if the answer is *yes*, isn't it redundant? isn't it equivalent to the next scenario: each *View* *object*  will have such a holder that will hold all it's data and the *View* only render itself according to the holder data?

Comment: (1) yes, sort of. it seems that `TabView`s are hosted in a container _inside_ the `TabLayout`, not as direct children. (2) Not sure I understand. Sure, a `TabView` could have private fields for text, icon, etc. But the API designers seem to have decided that it is better to create an object, `Tab`, to encapsulate all that data. That way, we can work with `Tab` instances and forget about the view, rather than mutating fields of a `TabView` object.

Comment: Thanks again :)  It's really interesting  me (some people may think i'm crazy), why the API designers have decided to use an additional object (*Tab*) whereas they could be "settle with* only **TabView** - exactly as it works with all other UI objects that inherit from a *View* object (e.g *TextView*)